# using livevalidation script - special characters except _ (underscore) - (hyphen) . (dot) and Space

Tags: javascript, jquery, livevalidation

I am using livevalidation script

> http://livevalidation.com

I need to check whether the text contains special characters except  _ (underscore) - (hyphen) . (dot) and Space
Presence of special characters except those characters will not validated 
What Cain I do for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are stuck with regular expression.

The regular expression is for your requirement is `/^[a-z0-9_ .-]*$/i`

```
var myField = new LiveValidation('myField', { validMessage: "I am valid!" });
myField.add(Validate.Format, { pattern: /^[a-z0-9_ .-]*$/i });
```